# Are $V=<(1,0,1),(1,1,1)>$ and $W=<(1,0,1),(0,1,0)>$ equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-subspace

I just wonder if we can treat vector spaces as matrices?

For example, are subspaces

$V=<(1,0,1),(1,1,1)>$ and $W=<(1,0,1),(0,1,0)>$ analogous?

Comment: Both are certainly $2$-dimensional. Can you show one way containment?

Comment: Are you asking if these two sets _span_ the same (sub)space?

Comment: Those sets are not subspaces.

Comment: @W.Joe  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, are subspaces
>
> $\color{blue}{V}=\{(1,0,1),(1,1,1)\}$ and $W=\{(1,0,1),(0,1,0)\}$ analogous?

It's easier to use different names so I renamed the first one to $V$.

Note that in the usual notation, you didn't give *subspaces* but simply two *sets* containing two elements (each).

The sets are (clearly) different ($V \ne W$) but they do ***span** the same subspace*:
$$\mbox{span}\,V=\mbox{span}\,W$$
In your case, this is easy to see because $(1,0,1)+(0,1,0)=(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the two subspaces are equivalent or equal indeed

$$(1,1,1)=(1,0,1)+(0,1,0)$$

and then

$$Span\{(1,0,1),(1,1,1)\}=Span\{(1,0,1),(0,1,0)\}$$